# Ruby : TypeError: can't convert String into Integer

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, jruby

I have JSON response.

```
result = {
  "owner":{
    "uid":"bb4123ac7950435eb516e2a47940b675",
    "firstName":"Tester",
    "lastName":"Test5577"
  }
}
```

I am trying to extract "uid" but getting the following error.

Ruby : TypeError: can't convert String into Integer

My code is:

```
@jdoc =JSON.parse(result)

@uid = @jdoc.fetch("owner").first.fetch("uid").to_i()   #Getting error here.
```

Would be very grateful for your support.

Comment: I have tried this on console and got the following result
`[29] pry(main)> @uid = @jdoc.fetch("owner").first.fetch("uid").to_i() 
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
from (pry):28:in `fetch'`
`[30] pry(main)> @uid = @jdoc.fetch("owner").fetch("uid").to_i() 
=> 0
[31] pry(main)> @uid = @jdoc.fetch("owner").fetch("uid")
=> "bb4123ac7950435eb516e2a47940b675"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change in your code should get the right data:

```
@jdoc = JSON.parse(result)
@uid = @json['owner']['uid'] #=> "bb4123ac7950435eb516e2a47940b675"
```

Also, you're trying to convert a string: "bb4123ac7950435eb516e2a47940b675" into integer: `to_i()` in your code. Which would be 0 as uid is a string of alphanumeric characters, and not a combination of some random numbers/integers. I would suggest that you save that information in a varchar column instead.

Comment: Thanks Surya. You are a star. It is working with @uid= @jdoc["owner"]["uid"]. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can access uid as follows:

```
@jdoc = JSON.parse(result)
@uid = @json['owner']['uid']
@uid = Integer(@uid) rescue 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please print what's inside `@jdoc` after `JSON.parse(result)`

btw the uid contain string so you'll receive 0 as ouput with integer

```
"bb4123ac7950435eb516e2a47940b675".to_i => # 0
"111".to_i => # 111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I hope this will help you.

```
@uid = @jdoc.fetch("owner").first.fetch("uid").to_i()

## OUTPUT

# If you do it like this you will get follwing error
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
```

But if you will do following you will get desire result.

```
@uid = @jdoc.fetch("owner").fetch("uid")

##OUTPUT

"bb4123ac7950435eb516e2a47940b675"
```